# Is my async method really async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Is function `AuditMarketStatusToDatabase`is indeed async?     `InfluxDbClient.Client.WriteAsync` is an external async method

```
        // main method
        // some code before
        AuditMarketStatusToDatabase(marketStatusPoints, database);
        // some code after

.
.
.

       private async void AuditMarketStatusToDatabase(List<Point> marketStatusPoints, string database)
       {
               await _influxDb.WritePointAsync(database, marketStatusPoints);
       }

       public async Task<bool> WritePointAsync(string dbName, List<Point> points)
       {
           IInfluxDataApiResponse response = await InfluxDbClient.Client.WriteAsync(dbName, points);
           return response.Success;
       }
```

Comment: It is an async fire-and-forget method, and the latter is rarely what you want. In fact, if you really want it to be fire-and-forget, you don't need to mark it async as the only thing you do internally is call another method, which you don't care about waiting for (fire-and-forget remember), in which case you can simply drop all async and await from it.

Comment: can you share a code example how to make is fire-and-forget?

Comment: What I mean by fire-and-forget is that you're not waiting for it to complete. "// some code after" has no guarantee that it will execute *after* `AuditMarketStatusToDatabase` has completed. In fact I would think it highly probable that the exact opposite will happen, "// some code after" will almost definitely execute while `AuditMarketStatusToDatabase` is still executing.

Comment: so if I understand currently, this is indeed fire-and-forget. this is what I want.. as `// some code after` is not related to the database data this is simply audit

Comment: Then I would remove the `async` from the method, as well as the `await` from it. This would make the internal call to `WritePointAsync` the fire-and-forget method. Note that you need to ensure that `_influxDb` is valid for the entire duration of the audit method, and with a fire-and-forget method this is hard to ensure. You sure you don't want to return a `Task` and wait for it after all? Note that you can wait for the task to complete at the very end of yoru code, after `//some code after` has executed, but *before*  you dispose of `_influxDb`.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but doesn't this belong in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/